# The std documentation examples with question marks don't compile

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm having extreme difficulties with the `try!` and `?` macro to the point that I'm starting to question the very fabric of reality. I lifted the example below [straight from the rust-docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) and it still blows up in my face.

**Code:**

```
pub use std::fs::File;
pub use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut file: File = File::open("foo.txt")?;
    file.write_all(b"Hello, world!")?;
}
```

**Error:**

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(): std::ops::Try` is not satisfied
--> src/main.rs:6:23
|
6 |     let mut file: File = File::open("foo.txt")?;
|                          ----------------------
|                          |
|                          the trait `std::ops::Try` is not implemented for `()`
|                          in this macro invocation
|
= note: required by `std::ops::Try::from_error`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `(): std::ops::Try` is not satisfied
--> src/main.rs:7:2
|
7 |     file.write_all(b"Hello, world!")?;
|     ---------------------------------
|     |
|     the trait `std::ops::Try` is not implemented for `()`
|     in this macro invocation
|
= note: required by `std::ops::Try::from_error`
```

I'm on the latest stable release of Rust according to `rustup` (1.19.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These examples are currently expected to be run wrapped in a function returning a `Result`; if you click Run in the upper right corner of the example, you will see that it expands to:

```
fn main() {
    use std::fs::File;
    use std::io::prelude::*;

    fn foo() -> std::io::Result<()> {
        let mut file = File::create("foo.txt")?;
        file.write_all(b"Hello, world!")?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

This is because functions returning `Result`s (like `File::create` and `io::Write::write_all`) should be handled with possible errors in mind (which is especially important in documentation examples).

There was an [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1176) to allow returning `Result` from `main()` that was already merged, though the [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43301) to allow `?`s in `main()` is still active.